# How does Clara obtain the clearance from UNIT as seen in the 50th anniversary?

Tags: doctor-who

As seen on the 50th anniversary, Kate Stewart (or the Zygon who looks like Kate Stewart) told Clara that she has a high level of clearance from her previous visit (and photos are shown).

At the time, it was thought that the photos were from a future episode, however, now that Clara's and the 11th Doctor's era are long gone it's never really clarified how she got that level of clearance or when were the photos taken, at least on the show.

Is it ever explained in any other form of media such as Interviews, comics or books or it's a plot hole?

Comment: Apply common sense. She was a companion of The Doctor. UNIT would obviously give her high level clearance..

Comment: @Bat I've updated the question to pinpoint exactly what I was talking about.

Comment: It is most certainly *not* a plot hole.  Nobody ever said that Clara's every waking moment must necessarily appear in some episode.  In fact it is strongly implied that she does lots of things offscreen in between rides on the TARDIS.  She wouldn't be much of a schoolteacher otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a plot hole, it's simply never explained.  It's centered on the idea that people who visit the Black Archives have their memories wiped, so she doesn't remember being there. Yes, someone could go back and write it as a novel or a Big Finish adventure, but it's funnier to leave it unspoken.

There's plenty of adventures we've never seen - we've seen a number of tail-ends of adventures at the beginning of completely unconnected new episodes We never saw her snog Jane Austen either, but that indisputably happened.

And the tale of Jim the Fish is one for which humanity is not yet ready.